# Simulação de Controle Remoto de TV

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde deve existir a possibilidade do usuário interagir com o programa, pressionando uma ou mais teclas numéricas para mudar a exibição de conteúdos multimídia (texto, áudio, vídeo e imagem) simultaneamente.

Atualmente o programa necessita do pressionamento de uma tecla entre 0 e 9 para navegar entre os tópicos, mas preciso expandir esta faixa para quaisquer valores acima de 9. Não é permitido o uso de quaisquer outras teclas para "confirmar" o deslocamento para um determinado tópico, por exemplo, pressionar "Enter".

Estou pesquisando uma forma do programa aguardar um intervalo de tempo, digamos 3 segundos, caso não seja pressionada nenhuma outra tecla neste intervalo, o programa "saltará" para o tópico correspondente a tecla pressionada, mas, se por outro lado, for pressionada uma segunda tecla, o programa deverá aguardar novamente mais 3 segundos, e em seguida "saltar" para o tópico correspondente ao valor das teclas pressionadas. (Não sei se me fiz entender, mas é como funciona um controle remoto de TV).

Qual ou quais classes em Java permitem fazer este tipo de verificação de tempo decorrido entre o pressionamento de uma tecla? Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, o que você precisa é de um temporizador! A classe Timer pode lhe ser útil.

Você vai precisar também pegar a data e hora do sistema, creio que seja mais fácil assim. Você pode fazer isto através de:

```
long tempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
//Pega a data e hora do sistema em milisegundos.
```

Ok, eu fiz um pequeno exemplo, espero que sirva para o que você quer. Funciona com um teclado de 0 a 9 e ele reseta o tempo a partir da ultima tecla digitada, possibilitando assim que você digite vários números. Depois de 3 segundos da última tecla digitada, é executada uma rotina.

Eis o código:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Tecla extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //Botões
    public JButton botao[][] = new JButton[4][3];
    //Conteúdo dos botões
    public String conteudo[][] = new String[4][3];
    //Texto dos botões
    public String texto = "123456789R0X";
    //Valor da tecla(s) pressionada(s)
    public String teclaPressionada = "";
    //Momento da ultima tecla pressionada
    public long tempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Momento atual
    public long tempoFim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Botão foi pressionado?
    public boolean pressionado = false;
    //Timer
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private TimerTask schedule;
    JTextField campo = new JTextField();

    public Tecla() {
        //Cria a janela, define tamanho, cor etc...
        final Container tela = getContentPane();
        tela.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        setTitle("Teclado");
        setSize(245, 362);
        setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100, 100));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setFocusable(true);

        //Cria botões
        for (int i = 0, cont = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                botao[i][j] = new JButton("<html><center><h1>" 
                        + texto.charAt(cont) + "</h1></center></html>");
                conteudo[i][j] = "" + texto.charAt(cont);
                botao[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 75));
                botao[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
                botao[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                botao[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                botao[i][j].setVisible(true);
                botao[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                tela.add(botao[i][j]);
                cont++;
            }
        }
        botao[3][2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
        campo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(238, 30));
        campo.setEditable(false);
        campo.setVisible(true);
        tela.add(campo);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Atualiza valor atual
        tempoFim = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (tempoFim - tempoInicio >= 3000) {
            reset();
        }
        loop:
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (e.getSource() == botao[3][2]) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (e.getSource() == botao[3][0]) {
                    reset();
                    break loop;
                }
                if (e.getSource() == botao[i][j]) {
                    tempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    botao[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 2));
                    if (!pressionado) {//Se pressionado for falso
                        pressionado = true;
                        teclaPressionada = conteudo[i][j];
                        break loop;
                    } else {
                        teclaPressionada += conteudo[i][j];
                        break loop;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void Temporizador() {
        schedule = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            //Função que é chamada a cada 100ms
            public void run() {
                //Imprime quanto tempo decorreu desde o ultimo botão pressionado
                System.out.println("Temporizador: " + (tempoFim - tempoInicio));
                tempoFim = System.currentTimeMillis();//Atualiza valor atual
                campo.setText(teclaPressionada);

                //Se demorou mais do que 3 segundos...
                if ((tempoFim - tempoInicio >= 3000)
                        && (!(teclaPressionada.isEmpty()))) {

                    //Faz alguma coisa:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Você apertou: " + teclaPressionada);

                    reset();//Reseta valores originais
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(schedule, 0, 100);//Executa tarefa a cada 100ms
    }

    public void reset() {
        pressionado = false;
        teclaPressionada = "";
        tempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Devolve a cor azul aos botões.
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                botao[i][j].setBorder(
                        new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
            }
        }
        botao[3][2].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
    }
}
```

**Importante**, você tem que chamar o método responsável pelo Timer, pode fazer isso logo depois de chamar o Frame:

```
Tecla tecla = new Tecla();
tecla.setVisible(true);
tecla.Temporizador();
```

Também pode lhe ser útil parar o Timer, para isto use:

```
schedule.cancel();
```

Se quiser retomar, basta chamar de novo.

Basicamente, eu pego a data-hora do sistema de quando a tecla foi pressionada, que é atualizada constantemente pelo Timer, e subtraio ela com a data-hora do sistema atual obtendo assim a diferença de tempo. O Timer executa a cada 100ms e contém um *if* que verifica se já passaram-se 3 segundos. Talvez não seja a melhor maneira de fazer isto, porém foi a forma que encontrei. Conto com a ajuda da comunidade para encontrar uma forma mais elegante de se fazer isto.

Ficou assim:

[image: Print da aplicação]

Comment: Caro Avelino, muito obrigado mesmo! Não tinha idéia de como inciar o trabalho, porém com seu exemplo ficou bastante elucidativo e vou tentar complementar de forma que possa ser utilizado com captura de teclas (Keylisteners), então postarei aqui meus resultados. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado a todos que estão colaborando! Abraços cordiais, Augusto Cesar

Comment: @AugustoCesardeSáNunes A maneira tradicional de agradecer alguém que respondeu sua pergunta com sucesso é **clicando no checkbox** que existe no lado esquerdo da resposta. Ao fazer isso você está selecionando aquela resposta como a oficial.