# Como deixar uma janela transparente utilizando Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, background

Estou desenvolvendo um trabalho de faculdade em `Qt`. Gostaria de deixar transparente o fundo da minha aplicação. Pesquisei um pouco e a função que encontrei foi:

```
this->setWindowOpacity(0);
```

Entretanto, o `Qt` aplica a opacidade em toda a janela. Gostaria que os componentes que eu adicionasse, como botões ou mesmo desenhos usando o `QPainter`, mantivessem suas opacidades normais, ou seja, não gostaria de aplicar opacidade nos componentes da janela, somente no frame.

Estou usando `Debian` 7.1 com o `Gnome` 3.4.2.

No momento estou tendo este resultado:

[image: Qt_transparente]

Observe que a transparência se aplicou ao botão também.

Removi algumas coisas da minha aplicação de modo a facilitar a resolução do meu problema. Segue o código:

**Janela.h**

```
#ifndef JANELA_H
#define JANELA_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>

class Janela: public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Janela();
    ~Janela();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);

public:
    QFrame *frame;
    QPushButton *botao;
    int pos_x=280,pos_y=280;
};

#endif // JANELA_H
```

**Janela.cpp**

```
#include <Janela.h>

Janela::Janela(){
    QFrame *frame = new QFrame();
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    this->setWindowOpacity(0.80);
    setCentralWidget(frame);
    setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Exemplo de QFrame"));

    frame->setLineWidth(4);
    frame->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
    frame->setFixedSize(300,300);
    frame->resize(300, 300);
    frame->setMinimumSize(300,300);
    frame->setMaximumSize(300,300);
    frame->setLayout(layout);

    botao = new QPushButton("Pressione-me");
    layout->addWidget(botao);

    show();
    frame->setFocus();

};

Janela::~Janela(){};

void Janela::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event){
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::green);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::green);
    painter.drawEllipse(10,10,10,10);
    painter.fillRect(pos_x,pos_y,10,10,Qt::red);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Janela.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Janela *janela = new Janela();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso ativando a flag `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` na `Janela` principal.

```
Janela::Janela() : QMainWindow(NULL, Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```

E, então, ative o atributo `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` para deixar o background invisível:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: Janela Transparent]

---

Para deixar o background translúcido, e não apenas invisível, você adicionar no PaintEvent o desenho do background que você quer. Exemplo:

```
QPainter painter(this);

// Para usar a cor padrão de background do sistema.
QColor background_color = palette().color(QPalette::Background);
background_color.setAlpha(128); 
painter.setBrush(QBrush(background_color));

// Define uma borda.
painter.setPen(QColor("#888"));

// Desenha o novo background da janela, antes de qualquer outra coisa.
painter.drawRect(0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);
```

E o resultado é esse:

[image: Janela com Transparência]

Comment: Explicação perfeita. Era exatamente isto que eu queria. Muito grato! =D

Percebi que assim como no Java, o Qt remove os botões de fechar. Mas isto não é um problema. Já que a janela vai ser fechada com um evento de teclado.(http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9367/simulacao-de-controle-remoto-de-tv/9396#9396)

Existe como reativá-los?

Comment: Acho que se reativar você perde a transparência. Mas, você também pode "simular" os botões do sistema também. Vai mais trabalho, mas não fica ruim. Fiz algo parecido para criar uma janela no estilo do Visual Studio: http://i.imgur.com/Ao0SH9P.png

Comment: Ficou muito bom. Você usou ícones nos botões? Estou desenvolvendo um Pacman: http://i.imgur.com/BTY9zaA.png   fiz a janela fechar quando o ESC é pressionado. Acho que é suficiente.

Grato pela ajuda. Isto vai me servir muito (Sou fã de frames transparentes).

Comment: São imagens mesmo, mas funcionam como os botões normais. No seu caso, como é um jogo, acho que o ESC fica até melhor, pois a maioria dos jogos sai em ESC. Só não esqueça de perguntar se o usuário tem certeza de que quer sair.